# CSS Content goes off the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to center the content but my content is going on the right side and goes off the screen

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: About Us
 */

$aboutheading = get_field('about_heading');
$aboutus = get_field('about_us');
get_header(); ?>

<section>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

        <h2> <?php echo "$aboutheading"; ?></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
        <p class="lead"><?php echo "$aboutus"; ?></p>
</div>
    </div>
 </div>
    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the live link:http://www.abiglittlebiz.com/trevelle/about-us/

what I'm trying to achieve that the div becomes responsive

Comment: You have a metric shitton of `&nbsp;`s in your content.

Comment: We need the rendered HTML and CSS, not the PHP. [mcve]

Comment: The issue is not in this code as far as I can tell. Whatever is producing the content for `$aboutus` is replacing all your spaces ( as eloquently put by Joseph ) with non-breaking ones. Check for any content filters or if you're pasting the content from elsewhere to determine the source of this.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6"> Is setting a fixed height and width on your page, Remove this div and put your content under it's parent

Comment: It's either the `get_field` method that's turning the spaces into non-breaking ones (which just to be clear means that they don't break to the next line when the text would normally wrap), or it's the source content that was copy/pasted or whatnot into the backend.  Looks like it's a wordpress site, so I'd assume that `get_field` is either wordpress native or the ACF plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in your $aboutus [Non-Breaking Space](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm)

In this case, text can't be break and go to new line. Clear Non-Breaking Spaces from your content or try this:

```
<p class="lead"><?php echo str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $aboutus); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments. The issue is not CSS. The issue is the content. All spaces have been replaced by `&nbsp;` in your content, which is keeping the browser from breaking lines.

Just to verify this you can add the rule `word-break: break-word;` to your div and notice that the lines will be forced to break mid-word and stay inside your div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use offset class.

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <h2> <?php echo "$aboutheading"; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
                <p class="lead"><?php echo "$aboutus"; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```